# Spring: right way to mock beans

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-test

**I have:** beans like

```
<bean id="abstractBean" class="com.package.MyBean" abstract="true"/>

<bean id="heirBean" parent="abstractBean">
    <property name="someProperty" ref="anotherBean">
</bean>
```

**Question:** How to mock `heirBean`? Or in other words how to mock `abstractBean`?

---

**======================== OPTIONAL PART OF QUESTION ==============================**

**How do I tried to do that [with exception]:**

```
<bean id="abstractBean" class="MockFactoryBean">
    <property name="type" value="com.package.MyBean"/>
</bean>
```

*MockFactoryBean.java*

```
public class MockFactoryBean<T> implements FactoryBean<T> {
    private Class<T> type;

    public void setType(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public T getObject() throws Exception {
        return Mockito.mock(type);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> getObjectType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Problem:** I can't set fields of mock.

Answer (score 1):

There is this framework that allows you to add mocking functionality to your spring xml file - https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home

Comment: @user346561 pls encounter advantages of springockito over my approach. I mean what it can that my approach can't. I'll accept your answer afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you don't mock parent beans, you mock each bean you want to mock.

As I understand your problem:

- you have many beans
- than use some common functionality
- you want to mock that common functionality

While the theory generally discourages refactoring for testing, the specific needs of the tests allow you to see the ways you could refactor your code.

I'd propose:

- moving the common functionality to the separate interface+implementation
- injecting that functionality to all your beans that use it
- mock that common functionality

Therefore you **replace inheritance with usage**, which allows you much more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the profile concept of spring; from spring 3.2.X there is the "profile" concept in Spring and you can use it to mock your bean for test scope

Comment: but if I need to mock one-two beans. Isn't it a big overhead to create a separate context for single mock?

Comment: well you can create this new application context (honestly i use the annotation so i don't need to create different application contexts) and you can load the new context file only for the test case

Comment: but if I have a really big app context, and I need to redefine the single bean of it?